# Object Reference Is Required "ProductService"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting the following Error when trying to use OOP (for the first time), to display a list of products on my aspx page. The ProductService.cs reads the query and parameters from my ProductService.cs file, but unforturnaly there seem to be an issue with this line of code:

```
ProductService.SaveProduct(id, TxtName.Text, Int32.Parse(DDCategories.SelectedValue), TxtDescription.Text, Decimal.Parse(TxtPrice.Text), Decimal.Parse(TxtUnitDiscount.Text));
```

**Error:**

> CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'ProductService.SaveProduct(int?, string, int,
>   string, decimal, decimal)'

Aspx.cs:

```
protected void BtnUpdateOrCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
               // Text in fields has to exist, if they are requierd
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxtName.Text) /*&&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxtDescription.Text)*/)
        {
            // TODO: Be sure to parse the decimals using TryParse before 
            int? id = isCreate ? null : (int?)ProductID;
            ProductService productService = new ProductService();
            ProductService.SaveProduct(id, TxtName.Text, Int32.Parse(DDCategories.SelectedValue), TxtDescription.Text, Decimal.Parse(TxtPrice.Text), Decimal.Parse(TxtUnitDiscount.Text));

            // Redirects to list
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
        }
```

ProductService.cs:

```
public void SaveProduct(int? id, string name, int categoryID, string description, decimal unitPrice, decimal discountUnitPrice)
    {
        dataAccess.AddParameter("@Name", name);
        dataAccess.AddParameter("@Category_ID", categoryID);
        dataAccess.AddParameter("@Description", description.ToNewline(false));
        dataAccess.AddParameter("@UnitPrice", unitPrice);
        dataAccess.AddParameter("@DiscountUnitPrice", discountUnitPrice);

        if (!id.HasValue)
        {
            // Insert query
            dataAccess.Execute(@"INSERT INTO [Product] ([Name], [Category_ID], [UnitPrice], [DiscountUnitPrice], [Description])
                                                VALUES (@Name, @Category_ID, @UnitPrice, @DiscountUnitPrice, @Description)");
        }
        else
        {
            // Update query
            dataAccess.AddParameter("@id", id.Value);
            dataAccess.Execute(@"UPDATE [Product]
                                SET [Name] = @Name, [Category_ID] = @Category_ID, [UnitPrice] = @UnitPrice, [DiscountUnitPrice] = @DiscountUnitPrice, [Description] = @Description
                                WHERE id = @id");
        }
    }
```

I can't seem to figure out what the issue could be, any response is more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ProductService.SaveProduct(id, TxtName.Text, Int32.Parse(DDCategories.SelectedValue),     TxtDescription.Text, Decimal.Parse(TxtPrice.Text), Decimal.Parse(TxtUnitDiscount.Text));
```

Should be

```
productService.SaveProduct(id, TxtName.Text, Int32.Parse(DDCategories.SelectedValue),     TxtDescription.Text, Decimal.Parse(TxtPrice.Text), Decimal.Parse(TxtUnitDiscount.Text));
```

You are instantiating the class, but afterwards you are not using the instantiated variable, common mistake when starting with a case sensitive language. Note the difference colors in visual studio for different objects.

The alternative would be to change the method: SaveProduct to [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx), but then all the private variables in the ProductService class that you use in the SaveProduct method will have to be static as well, if you choose this method rather make the whole class [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx).

Comment: This did the job! And thank you for the extra info, I will mark this as the answer because 1. It did the job and 2. it has some good informations about case sensitivity and more which could be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
ProductService.SaveProduct(id, TxtName.Text, Int32.Parse(DDCategories.SelectedValue), TxtDescription.Text, Decimal.Parse(TxtPrice.Text), Decimal.Parse(TxtUnitDiscount.Text));
```

to this

```
productService.SaveProduct(id, TxtName.Text, Int32.Parse(DDCategories.SelectedValue), TxtDescription.Text, Decimal.Parse(TxtPrice.Text), Decimal.Parse(TxtUnitDiscount.Text));
```

You are making a call to the class name `ProductService` and method name (as if it is a static method) not the instance you have created `productService`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `ProductService` is class name - not variable.
You should create instance of the class to use it's method:

```
ProductService srv = new ProductService();
srv.SaveProduct(id, TxtName.Text, Int32.Parse(DDCategories.SelectedValue), TxtDescription.Text, Decimal.Parse(TxtPrice.Text), Decimal.Parse(TxtUnitDiscount.Text));
```

If you want to use it as you posted - you should add `static` to your method signature:

```
public static void SaveProduct(int? id, string name, int categoryID, string description, decimal unitPrice, decimal discountUnitPrice)
```